# converting rgb image to double and keeping the values in matlab

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image and I want to import this image to matlab. I am using the following code. The problem that I have is that when I convert the image to grayscale, everything will be changed and the converted image is not similar to original one. In another words, I want to keep the values (or let say the image) as it is in the original image. Is there any way for doing this?

[image]

```
I = imread('myimage.png');
figure, imagesc(I), axis equal tight xy

I2 = rgb2gray(I);
figure, imagesc(I2), axis equal tight xy
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original image is already using a `jet` colormap. The problem is, when you convert it to grayscale, you lose some crucial information. See the image below.

[image]

In the original image you have a heatmap. Blue areas generally indicate "low value", whereas red areas indicate "high values". But when converted to grayscale, both areas indicate low value, as they aproach dark pixels (see the arrows).

A possible solution is this:

> You take **every** pixel of your image, find the nearest (closest)
>   color value in the `jet` colormap and use its index as a gray value.

I will show you first the final code and the results. The explanation goes below:

```
I = im2double(imread('myimage.png'));

map = jet(256);
Irgb = reshape(I, size(I, 1) * size(I, 2), 3);
Igray = zeros(size(I, 1), size(I, 2), 'uint8');
for ii = 1:size(Irgb, 1)
    [~, idx] = min(sum((bsxfun(@minus, Irgb(ii, :), map)) .^ 2, 2));
    Igray(ii) = idx - 1;
end
clear Irgb;

subplot(2,1,1), imagesc(I), axis equal tight xy
subplot(2,1,2), imagesc(Igray), axis equal tight xy
```

Result:

[image]

```
>> whos I Igray
  Name         Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  I          110x339x3            894960  double              
  Igray      110x339               37290  uint8
```

**Explanation:**

First, you get the `jet` colormap, like this:

```
map = jet(256);
```

It will return a `256x3` colormap with the possible colors on the jet palette, where each row is a RGB pixel. `map(1,:)` would be kind of a dark blue, and `map(256,:)` would be kind of a dark red, as expected.

Then, you do this:

```
Irgb = reshape(I, size(I, 1) * size(I, 2), 3);
```

... to turn your `110x339x3` image into a `37290x3` matrix, where each row is a RGB pixel.

Now, for each pixel, you take the Euclidean distance of that pixel to the `map` pixels. You take the index of the nearest one and use it as a gray value. The minus one (`-1`) is because the index is in the range 1..256, but a gray value is in the range 0..255.

**Note:** the Euclidean distance takes a square root at the end, but since we are just trying to find the closest value, there is no need to do so.

**EDIT:**

Here is a 10x faster version of the code:

```
I = im2double(imread('myimage.png'));
map = jet(256);
[C, ~, IC] = unique(reshape(I, size(I, 1) * size(I, 2), 3), 'rows');
equiv = zeros(size(C, 1), 1, 'uint8');
for ii = 1:numel(equiv)
    [~, idx] = min(sum((bsxfun(@minus, C(ii, :), map)) .^ 2, 2));
    equiv(ii) = idx - 1;
end
Irgb = reshape(equiv(IC), size(I, 1), size(I, 2));
Irgb = Irgb(end:-1:1,:);
clear equiv C IC;
```

It runs faster because it exploits the fact that the colors on your image are restricted to the colors in the `jet` palette. Then, it counts the `unique` colors and only match them to the palette values. With fewer pixels to match, the algorithm runs much faster. Here are the times:

- **Before:**

  Elapsed time is 0.619049 seconds.
- **After:**

  Elapsed time is 0.061778 seconds.

Comment: Glad to help! I've edited my answer to include a 10x faster version of the code. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it was too much for me :)

Answer (score 0):

In the second image, you're using the default [`colormap`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/colormap.html), i.e. `jet`.  If you want grayscale, then try using `colormap(gray)`.

Comment: I need its values, because after converting to grayscale, the values change and the colormap does not change the image

Comment: @Sam: It's not clear what you're asking, then.  By converting to grayscale, you're throwing away information (i.e. hue and saturation).  You can't recover that information.

Comment: Then how I can have the same image (by using anything else)? Because the values of original image is very important for me and I want to have it in a 2D matrix.

Comment: @Sam: If the values of the original RGB image are important, then don't convert to grayscale!

Comment: Actually I want to have that image in a 2D matrix, that is why I am converting to grayscale! is there another way to escaping from converting to grayscale and have the original image in a 2D matrix?

Comment: @Sam: You could flatten the 3rd dimension with a combination of `reshape` and transposition.  i.e. you start with a MxNx3 array, and end up with an Mx(3N) matrix.

Comment: Would you please change your answer then?

Comment: @Sam: Are you sure a M x 3N matrix is what you want?  Looking at your discussion, it doesn't seem like this is what you're looking for.  Also, would it be possible to use a 2D matrix of cell values, where each cell contains the RGB vector?

Comment: @rayryeng: I need a 2D matrix at the end (MxN). I did not catch your mean your mean by using 2D matrix of rgb.

Comment: @sam: unless you can clarify your original question to explain exactly what you want the output to be, I'm not sure this is answerable.